# How to decompile this kind of XML file? [Weird Characters]

Tags: android, xml, encryption, apk

Good Day,
       I've been unable to decrypt an XML file

Here is a sample of the code extracted from Building.XML

```
ØŒˆOZ[ARED^XY
RYTXS^YP
bcq    :=tXYQ^PooyVZR
ÒŒÐš¦Þ²ºÐŠ™ß–Ÿc_ERVS
c_ERVS
```

I tried searching XML decompiler or related sources but none of them solved my problem..

If any kind souls wish to take a deeper look into the source, here is the URL:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bzvm-CMwtMm2d0tQVGJDdzYwNzQ/edit?usp=sharing

Hope through this portal I can find a satisfying answer

Thank you very much and have a great day ahead!

Comment: Where did you take such a file? Are you allowed to inspect its contents?

Comment: The fact you've added the "apk" tag to your question suggests you are trying to reverse engineer an Android apk file...correct?

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_(file_format) it is similar to a .jar file and hence Zipped.  Try unzipping it first.

Comment: @Squonk Yes I am trying to reverse engineer an android apk.

Comment: @rossum I already unzipped the apk with apktool but it is the xml files in the extracted componenets that confuses me